# Sacred Huntsmaster with Animal Domain

Tags: pathfinder-1e

[Sacred Huntsmaster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/archetypes/paizo---inquisitor-archetypes/sacred-huntsmaster)

> At 1st level, a sacred huntsmaster forms a bond with an animal companion. This ability works as the hunter class feature of the same name, using her inquisitor level as her hunter level.
>
> This ability replaces judgment 1/day.

[Animal Domain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/animal-domain)

> Animal Companion (Ex): At 4th level, you gain the service of an animal companion. Your effective druid level for this animal companion is equal to your cleric level – 3. (Druids who take this ability through their nature bond class feature use their druid level – 3 to determine the abilities of their animal companions).

This combo allows you to have 2 animal companions.
It seems ridiculously strong to allow the secondary hunter bonuses such as the animal aspect and teamwork feat sharing to work on the domain-given animal companion. However depending on how you read the text in these class features, you could argue it would.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

## This combination does *not* allow 2 animal companions

It's unfortunate, but it's true. The hunter's class feature [animal companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/hunter#TOC-Animal-Companion-Ex-) says

> At 1st level, a hunter forms a bond with an animal companion. A hunter may begin play with any of the animals available to a druid. This animal is a loyal companion that accompanies the hunter on her adventures. This ability functions like the druid animal companion ability (which is part of the nature bond class feature). The hunter's effective druid level is equal to her hunter level. **If a character receives an animal companion from more than one source, her effective druid levels stack for the purposes of determining the companion's statistics and abilities.** A hunter may teach her companion hunter's tricks from the skirmisher ranger archetype instead of standard tricks.

Emphasis mine. Thus a [sacred huntsmaster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/archetypes/paizo---inquisitor-archetypes/sacred-huntsmaster) [Inquisitor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor) 4 with the [animal domain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/animal-domain) has an [animal companion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions) as if he were a [druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid) of (his inquisitor level) + (his inquisitor level −3), making for a superior animal companion (for his animal companion class feature he's an effective Druid 20 ([the maximum](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement)) at Inquisitor 12), but such a character *deserves* a beefy animal companion, having devoted *a lot* of his resources to this class feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you would not get to share your feats with your second companion from the animal domain because Hunter Tactics is specific in that it says "your animal companion".

Compare this to the hunter archetype packmaster which is a hunter made to have multiple pets

> A packmaster's precise companion, woodland stride, and **teamwork feats apply to only one of her animal companions at a time**.

The Hunter Tactics ability is talking about a specific ability "animal companion" granted to you by the class--not by any other ability you may also have (even if it does have the same name).